# A dockerized C++ windows console application exited with code 3221225781

Tags: c++, docker

I Have written a very simple c++ hello world program

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
   std::cout << "Hello Docker world!\n";
   return 0;
}
```

This is build as a release x64 windows console application and thus produces an exe

than I dockerize this program using the following dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore

ADD ./DockerHello.exe /DockerHello.exe

# Run exe when the container launches
CMD C:\DockerHello.exe
```

However when i use docker run it will show nothing and when i use docker ps -a I see that it has exited with code 3221225781

From some online searching I understand that this apparently means that I am missing some dll or so, but I have no idea how to find out which?

Can anybody help me? Or tell me how I can get a simple c++ console application working in docker?

Comment: How did you link `DockerHello.exe` for the runtime? Did you use `/MT` or `/MD`, if using MSVC? If you don't have the MSVC runtime in the Docker container and linked with `/MD`, it could fail to find the DLLs it requires.

Comment: I am using MSVS 2017. I do not understand what you mean by linking with /MD or /MT so it could very well be my problem

Comment: Every C or C++ application needs a runtime, a library that contains the core functionality of the C standard library (or C++), and MSVC allows you to statically link to a runtime when compiling code, so the runtime does not need to be installed on the computer the code is run on:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx

Comment: If you've ever wondered why you need to install "Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 20XX" sometimes when running a new application, it's because the code was linked to a shared runtime (`/MD`), and so Windows needs to install that version of the runtime (a DLL) to use the code.

Comment: A solution would either to be install the redistributable package for MSVC 2017, or to link statically, if that is indeed the cause of the issue. Either works.

Comment: It was set to /MD I made it /MT and now it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As confirmed in the comments, the issue stems from the runtime library not being present on the Docker image for code compiled from MSVC.

To solve this, you may either:

1. Statically link to the runtime, using the `/MT` flag.
2. Install the correct runtime on the docker image.

## Static Linking

The `/MT` flag (or variants) must be passed to msbuild, which through Visual Studio can be done as follows (from Microsoft's [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx)):

> Open the project's Property Pages dialog box. For details, see How to: Open Project Property Pages.
>   Expand the C/C++ folder.
>   Select the Code Generation property page.
>   Modify the Runtime Library property.

## Install Runtime

To install the correct runtime, you must install the redistributable while building of the docker image.

```
ADD $url /vc_redist.exe
RUN C:\vc_redist.exe /quiet /install
```

For Visual Studio, these are the correct URL (as of today's date, feel free to edit to update):

Where the `$url` is the path to the correct Visual Studio Redistributable (links provided below):

- Visual Studio 2017, [x86](https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/d0b808a8-aa78-4250-8e54-49b8c23f7328/9c5e6532055786367ee61aafb3313c95/vc_redist.x86.exe), [x86-64](https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/9fbed7c7-7012-4cc0-a0a3-a541f51981b5/e7eec15278b4473e26d7e32cef53a34c/vc_redist.x64.exe)
- Visual Studio 2015, [x86](https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/F/93FCF1E7-E6A4-478B-96E7-D4B285925B00/vc_redist.x86.exe), [x86-64](https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/F/93FCF1E7-E6A4-478B-96E7-D4B285925B00/vc_redist.x64.exe)
- Visual Studio 2013, [x86](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/E/6/2E61CFA4-993B-4DD4-91DA-3737CD5CD6E3/vcredist_x86.exe), [x86-64](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/E/6/2E61CFA4-993B-4DD4-91DA-3737CD5CD6E3/vcredist_x64.exe)

## Docker Image Selection

As the OP notes in the comments, the `microsoft/nanoserver` image is sufficient when using static runtime linking, however, if using shared runtime linking, you should use the `microsoft/windowsservercore` image, otherwise, the installation of the redistributable fails.

Comment: I found that with static linking the image microsoft/nanoserver is enough however when I use the install runtime approach I need to use microsoft/windowsservercore (otherwise install of vc_redist fails) so that might be a factor in choosing either of the two solutions

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you are using the wrong docker image. Looking at [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/issues/15#issuecomment-294613714) issue on github it looks like you need to be using the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.6.2

ADD https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/A/A/6AA4EDFF-645B-48C5-81CC-ED5963AEAD48/vc_redist.x64.exe /vc_redist.x64.exe
RUN C:\vc_redist.x64.exe /quiet /install

ADD ./DockerHello.exe /DockerHello.exe

CMD C:\DockerHello.exe
```

P.S. I don't have windows to test this on, but if you play around with it, it should be working. Maybe it might work with the `microsoft/windowsservercore` image as well.

Comment: The Docker image isn't the issue, but installing the VC Redistributable is a great guess (and confirmed in the comments).

Comment: Actually i made it microsoft/windowsservercore in order to try and fix it previously. Now that I have it working it seems that microsoft/nanoserver also will do as an image as long as I use static linking

Answer (score 0):

You can see the problem by using docker logs:

```
docker logs <container name or ID>
```

Comment: I had found this before but it does not display anything for me